# using Rabbitmq client in .core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I am building an application in .net core 2.0 and we have a requirement to subscribe and publish messages to RabbitMQ. Could find NuGet package which uses standard .net library[a hell lot of DLLs get added]. however, I am looking for pure .net core application which can be hosted in Linux as well.

Does anyone has implemented the same stuff?

Comment: http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html  says it supports .net core from 4.0

Comment: yes, but it's with standard library.. not especially for core

Comment: libraries should generally always target standard now so they can be used by all the .NET stacks

Comment: standard means it should be cross platform

Comment: so do you think i should be using the NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client# and build? with this can I deploy the app on Linux or any other platform where .netframework is not installed?

Comment: again will this be lightweight?

Comment: you need to make your own call on whatever you think lightweight is.  Either way,  .net standard is going to be the normal for libraries that are intended for any of the .net platforms, you'll likely never see things like this have a specific .NET core library.